# FastMM reports memory leak for record thread variable

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, delphi-xe2, fastmm

FastMM reports a memory leak (UnicodeString) for the following code snippet that uses a record thread variable with a string:

```
program Project10;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  FastMM4,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TContext = record
    Value : String;
  end;

threadvar
  Context : TContext;

begin
Context.Value := 'asdfsdfasfdsa';
end.
```

Is this a real memory leak or is the cleanup of thread variables just happening after FastMM checks for memory leaks?

Even more important: how can I suppress these "memory leaks" being reported as they clutter up any other memory leaks that might be found?

Comment: I believe the thread must cleanup dynamic values? Try to add Context.Value := '' in thread cleanup code.

Comment: This is part of my logging code, so I cannnot control thread cleanup since this might be called from any thread.

Comment: If you don't have access to the threads, then why are you using thread variables to begin with? What are you using them for exactly? Since you don't control the threads, the only other way I know to detect thread terminations is to write and load a DLL so you can receive `DLL_THREAD_DETACH` notifications. But then the DLL would need to manage the thread variable memory, unless you share FastMM across the DLL boundary.

Comment: @Remy You would not need to share FastMM in that situation. The DLL would be trivial. Load it up and call a function that it exports passing callbacks to receive the notifications. Then those notifications can run in the context of the host.

Comment: Well, as I said, the context is part of the logging. Each thread that is logging something has its own context (containing information about the thread and any context information that the thread decided to set).

Comment: FWIW your example code won't report a memory leak. It doesn't set the flag that enables leak reporting. And it won't leak anyway since your string is a non-modifiable string.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well I tried and it does definitely report a leak on XE2. Note that I include FastMM4 unit.

Comment: I'm surprised. The string you have should surely be a constant string with ref count -1. But I see I was wrong about ReportMemortLeaksAtShutdown since you are clearly using full fastmm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a real leak. Thread local variables are not finalized when they go out of scope. Because your record contains a field that is managed, the string field, the heap allocated memory associated with that string is leaked if the record is not finalized.

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Variables) calls this out explicitly:

> Dynamic variables that are ordinarily managed by the
>   compiler (long strings, wide strings, dynamic arrays, variants,
>   and interfaces) can be declared with threadvar, but the compiler does not automatically free the heap-allocated
>   memory created by each thread of execution. If you use
>   these data types in thread variables, it is your responsibility
>   to dispose of their memory from within the thread, before
>   the thread terminates.

If you want to plug the leak, you'll need to finalize the variable as the scope ends. That is, as the thread is terminating.

```
Finalize(Context);
```

Note that you must execute this code from the thread which owns the variable since, obviously, only that thread has access to it.

If you want to suppress reporting of these leaks then call RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak.

If you cannot execute code when threads terminate then it may be better to avoid heap allocation and use a fixed length character array. Quite possibly that you meet your needs.

It would seem odd that you claim not to be able to execute code when the threads terminate. If you cannot do that, how are you able to execute any code in the context of these threads. In other words, in order for there to be a leak, you must have executed your code in these threads.

Comment: Hi David, please see my comment to the question...it seems to me that there is no way for me to know when a thread terminates since I have no control of these threads.

Comment: If you want to avoid leaking these strings then you'll need to change something about your design. I've added a few suggestions.

Comment: I didn't decide yet what to do (RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak is not an option since I don't know how many are leaking which depends on the number of threads that log something). I will leave my question open for some time so that others can contribute as well, after which I'll accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create global array of TContext, and then store index of the element, that belongs to your thread, in a threadvar.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. But even so, what are you going to do with this global array? Wait until termination and then finalize all the records? In which case it's just the same as RegisterExpectedMemoryLeak. Or did you mean to do something else with this array. Oh, and obviously access to the array must be synchronised. Which would hurt performance.

Comment: I don't think there's need to syncronize the entire array, since only one element will be modified per thread.

Comment: @Fabricio What happens when a new thread is created and the array has to be re-sized?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: there's the only occasion it'll be needed and I bet it'll be an rare event. If you create 100 (in an absurd example) threads, and 20 threads finish, when a new thread is needed you does not need to size up the array.

Comment: @Fabricio That's not how I would approach multi-threaded coding. Hoping that unlikely events don't happen.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it's a matter of how many array items you preallocate beforehand.

Comment: @Fabricio What happens if you run out of slots?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Even an 10 hyper threaded quad core processor can have only 80 running threads. Overallocate or create an pool structure using jagged arrays to access it transparently. The idea is make it the nearest to a connection pool.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan 'Even with' and "processor's machine"... Oh my, what hurry doesn't do...

Comment: @Fabricio Server applications often have hundreds maybe thousands of threads in a process.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "Server applications with thousands of threads" but how many **executing**? Certainly not more than the maximum supported by hardware... And an 5000 array of Pointer is not what I call a great problem in a server dozens of GB of ram... I would like to discuss it more, David. But DBA duty calls... Tks a lot. ;-)

Comment: @Fabricio Doesn't matter how many are executing. Each thread has its own context. Storing 5000 or more elements is no problem. The issue is that your idea is to deny the need for array reallocation which seems to me to be impractical.